# How to make a discount on specific products quantity that have specific fields

Tags: rules, commerce

I'm a bit lost with a workcase.

I'd like to apply a discount to a few line items depending on their quantity and if the product if the line items have some specific fields.

An example will be a bit clearer:
If the user orders at least 10 differents product that share the same field value (let's say 5 different tshirt with the same color), the 10 corresponding line items in the order get a 5% discount.

I'm not familiar with rules.
I tried to make some loop on line items but i'm really in the dark here.

Some advices?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you're using taxonomy fields for your color on your shirts. If you are, then your solution is easy because [Commerce Taxonomy Conditions](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_taxonomy_conditions) will do the job. You can have it set to a quantity of a particular taxonomy field being present in an order and have it apply some discount.